# Django rest framework and getting serializer values using source keyword

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have two models, one is just the base `User` model and the other is `Profile` model that is used to extend the `User` model and keep more details.

Here's what the `UserSerializer` looks like:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from profiles.models import Profile
from rest_framework import serializers


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    reputation = serializers.IntegerField(
        read_only=True,
        source='profile.reputation'
    )

    class Meta:
        exclude = ('password',)
        model = User

    def create(self, validated_data):
        password = validated_data.get('password')
        user = User.objects.create(**validated_data)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()

        Profile.objects.create(user=user)

        return user
```

As you can see, this overrides the create method so it can make a profile record with each create.  There is also a `reputation` field being added to the serializer so when I get the `User` it comes with its reputation from the profile.  That `reputation` field is defined on the `Profile` model.

This got me thinking, is it possible to override `create` in such a way that allows me to send data to one endpoint and create profiles in one go?  For instance, right now if I want to create users and I just send a `POST` request to my endpoint with:

```
{
    "username": "sethen",
    "password": "password"
}
```

And I get back the correct profile.  If I were to add a `bio` field to my `Profile` model and put it in the `UserSerializer` and send it along with a `POST` like so:

```
{
    "bio": "It's me, Sethen!",
    "username": "sethen",
    "password": "password"
}
```

And then try to access that in my `create` method, I get a `KeyError` with `validated_data.pop('reputation')`.

Right now in my API you can update the profiles of users separately with another endpoint... However, I am wondering if I can update the user and the profile with one endpoint using the `create` method in my `UserSerializer` somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `'reputation'` data is nested in a dict under the `'profile'` key. You need to pop that dict and pass it to Profile:

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    profile_data = validated_data.pop('profile')
    password = validated_data.get('password')
    user = User.objects.create(**validated_data)
    user.set_password(password)
    user.save()

    Profile.objects.create(user=user, **profile_data)

    return user
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  Worked perfectly!